# Why to have files in localsystem in Phonegap ? (and not have them in the server)

Tags: cordova

Phonegap runs the HTML files in the localsystem, but if I say to phonegap to load an "http://whatever.com/page.php" instead of the default localhost index.html, it works too.

And if I run things like geolocation, accelerometer, or other plugins , they work too.

Having all pages in server allows me to change anything I want without having to upgrade an app (building, uploading to market, waiting to be published in case of iTunes, ...)

I see just advantages ...

Then ... why the local pages in Phonegap if you can run more comfortable things in server ?

(I assume the app **NEEDS** Internet connection)

Comment: Because if you have everything on your server the app can't be used without an Internet connection.

Comment: Just that ? My app needs Internet yes or yes ... it has no sense without connection ... if it's just that , I still see no advantages having all local